# Receiving binary data using request module in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: ajax, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the Add-on builder and I need to receive binary data (image). I would like to do this using the `request` module but as you can see from the documentation:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html

There are only `text` and `json` properties and `raw` is absent.

How should I receive binary data in the add-on script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this using the `request` module, you will have to use the regular `XMLHttpRequest` via [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html). Something like this should work:

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var request = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                .createInstance(Ci.nsIJSXMLHttpRequest);
request.open("GET", "...");
request.onload = function()
{
  onUnload.unload();

  var arrayBuffer = request.response;
  if (arrayBuffer)
  {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    ...
  }
};
request.onerror = function()
{
  onUnload.unload();
}
request.send(null);

var onUnload = {
  unload: function()
  {
    // Make sure to abort the request if the extension is disabled
    try
    {
      request.abort();
    }
    catch (e) {}
  }
};
require("unload").ensure(onUnload);
```

The mechanism to ensure that the request is aborted if your extension is suddenly disabled is rather awkward, that's the main reason the `request` module exists rather than simply giving you `XMLHttpRequest`. Note that it is important to call `onUnload.unload()` once the request finishes, otherwise the Add-on SDK will keep it in the list of methods to be called on unload (a memory leak). See [documentation of `unload` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/api-utils/docs/unload.html).

Comment: If you do use this in your add-on, it will make the review process ( and testing! ) easier if you put this code into a discrete module.

Comment: @canuckistani It seems a good idea but how do I actually put the codes into a discrete module?

Comment: The SDK uses the commonJS format, you will find an explanation in the docs here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/addon-development/commonjs.html