# XMLHttpRequest in a ContentScript from the Firefox SDK (Cross-Domain)

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I am porting a chrome extension to firefox and want to keep as much code as possible. I am working with the sdk and I am new with JavaScript, so please bear with me if it is just a nooby mistake ;)

I need to get some stuff via a couple of XMLHttpRequests in content-scripts.

The "firefox-way" of doing things would be to use the sdk-request-api and work via messages between the main- and the content-script like [so](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html). Besides the fact that it would mean a lot of work for me to implement this throughout the whole addon, I also need to get binary data, which seems not to be possible.

The workaround for this is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861632/receiving-binary-data-using-request-module-in-firefox-add-on-sdk). I would prefer to avoid this, since I think I read somewhere that it is a beta-feature right now and it seems to be pretty "work-aroundy".

Ideally I would like to implement it [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-24/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/cross-domain.html) way. In the upcoming Firefox 24 it should be possible to allow content scripts to access certain domains. Therefore I am using Firefox Aurora right now. I added the following code to my *package.json*:

```
"permissions": {
      "cross-domain-content": ["http://mozilla.org"]
 }
```

My *main.js* creates a panel when a button is clicked and loads the scripts into it:

```
var testPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
                contentURL: data.url("pages/background.html"),
                contentScriptFile:   [data.url("util/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"), data.url("pages/xhrTest.js")]
            })
testPanel.show();
```

And this is my *xhrTest.js*:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://mozilla.org",true);
xhr.onerror = function () {
   console.log("Error");
};
xhr.onload = function () {
   console.log("loaded");
}

xhr.send();
```

While debugging, it jumps from status 2 to 4 with an empty response and calls the "onerror". The status is 0, statustext is empty and I don't see any other indicators of what went wrong.
Now I don't know if this is still the same-origin-policy blocking me, or if I did something else wrong?

I'd really appreciate any help I can get :)

Thanks in advance,
Fabi

Answer (score 2):

Hrm, I can't really see a glaring error. Here is an example add-on based on the docs that *does* work, at least it does for me in Firefox 24 Beta:

Main.js:

```
// main.js
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  height: 250,
  contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("panel-script.js")
});

panel.on("show", function(){
  panel.port.emit("show");
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  id: "test-widget",
  label: "Test-Widget",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  panel: panel
});
```

Panel.html:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre id="forecast_summary"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Content script:

```
// panel-script.js
var url = "https://hn-test.firebaseio.com/articles/e5b10c82600b51732af584583a7f57c4a7c01bff.json";

self.port.on("show", function () {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onload = function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("forecast_summary");
    // formatting
    var pretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(request.responseText), null, '  ');
    element.textContent = pretty;
  };
  request.send();
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jp-crossdomain-xhr",
  "fullName": "jp-crossdomain-xhr",
  "id": "jid1-B2RaQxOBKox8wA",
  "description": "a basic add-on",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["https://hn-test.firebaseio.com"]
  }
}
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/canuckistani/jp-crossdomain-xhr)

Comment: Hey
Thanks for your reply! I cloned your repo and it works, both in FF 23.0 & 25.0a2. Funny enough, if I change the string in the *package.json* to something different ("asdf"), 23.0 still works, 25 throws an "URI is malformed". If I put a valid URL ("http://mozilla.org") in the *package.json*, both will succesfully pull the data.
But if I change the URL in the *panel-script* to "http://www.mozilla.org" (same thing in the *package.json*), the request exits with an error. Why? Because of the server?

Shouldn't 23.0 not at all be able to execute the request? And 25.0a2 only if the domains match?

Comment: I've no idea - my example works as-is with matching urls, and does not work if you change the urls to mis-match.